# Loader animation using Custom View in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

Posted this question on CodeReview, but did not got much response. Link to code review [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58207/loader-animation-using-custom-view-in-android)

I created a loader animation for an Android app: a simple 3 dots loader.

It is working. But is this the correct way to animate by using TimerTask?

```
public class ThreeDotsLoader extends View {

Paint dot1;
Paint dot2;
Paint dot3;

int defaultColor;
int highlightColor;

boolean animationStarted = false;

TimerTask task;
Timer timer;

int count = 1;

public ThreeDotsLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    defaultColor = Color.rgb(44, 78, 82);
    highlightColor = Color.WHITE;

    initPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d("custom", "ondraw");
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 15, dot1);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 50, 15, dot2);
    canvas.drawCircle(150, 50, 15, dot3);
}

private void initPaint(){
    dot1 = new Paint();
    dot1.setColor(defaultColor);
    dot1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    dot1.setAntiAlias(true);


    dot2 = new Paint();
    dot2.setColor(defaultColor);
    dot2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    dot2.setAntiAlias(true);

    dot3 = new Paint();
    dot3.setColor(defaultColor);
    dot3.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    dot3.setAntiAlias(true);
}

public void startLoading(){
    task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            switch(count){
            case 1:
                dot1.setColor(highlightColor);
                dot2.setColor(defaultColor);
                dot3.setColor(defaultColor);
                count++;
                break;
            case 2:
                dot1.setColor(defaultColor);
                dot2.setColor(highlightColor);
                dot3.setColor(defaultColor);
                count++;
                break;
            case 3:
                dot1.setColor(defaultColor);
                dot2.setColor(defaultColor);
                dot3.setColor(highlightColor);
                count = 1;
                break;
            }
            animationStarted = true;
            postInvalidate();
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 300);

}

public void stopLoading(){
    animationStarted = false;
    timer.cancel();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is working. But is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I suggest using [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that there is some [advantages](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.ca/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html)

```
While rescheduling Handler is very easy, you can not reschedule Timer    

In Handler you can attach to any Runnable but Timer schedule for only one TimerTask

TimerTask is purely background task so you can not update UserInterface, but that's not true for Handler's Runnables
```